# Get all th tags under thead only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a simple html table, which containg thead, tbody and tfoot.
I want to select using javascript or jquery all th tags only within the thead.
So far, I found a way to get either all th in table or the thead itself.

My table:

```html
<table id="MyTbl" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Desc
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="MyTableBody">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr height="27px">
            <th class="TDHMain">
                FILTER ID
            </th>
            <th class="TDHMain">
                FILTER NAME
            </th>
            <th class="TDHMain">
                FILTER DESC
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My javascript:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('MyTbl');
var tableHeader = table.getElementsByTagName('thead');
var headers = tableHeader.getElementsByTagName('th'); //This one doesn't work. No such a method for the thead tag
```

I also tried the following code:

```js
headers = $('#MyTbl').find('thead > th').get();
```

But as a result I couldn't really understand how to work with it... It's not an array, there's no foreach function to the headers object I get as a result, and I really couldn't find a way to reach the data.

Is there anyway to get just the th elements within the thead of a table?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can push all your text into an array:

```
var thArray = [];

$('#MyTbl > thead > tr > th').each(function(){
    thArray.push($(this).text())
})
```

Then retrieve it like this:

```
thArray[0]; // This will give you ID
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Crf6k/)**

Answer (score 3):

**No Jquery 2018**

```
let headers = document.querySelectorAll("#myTbl > thead > tr > th")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this;

```
$('#MyTbl thead').find('th');
```

**OR**

```
$('#MyTbl thead th').each(function() {
    // Your code per th here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var tableHead = $('#MyTbl thead tr th');
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery normal CSS selector such as `$('#MyTbl thead th')` works. But you can also use scoped selector.  To use scoped selector, you mention the scope as second argument as

`$('th','thead').css('color','red');`

Here second argument `thead` provides the scope.
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtnds18h/1/)  for example

Answer (score 0):

Oh ! I missed the "tr".

I solved it the following way:

```
headers = $('#MyTbl').find('thead > tr > th').get();
```

Comment: Probably costed you more time to post the question than try solving your own problem. Good luck coding :)

Comment: hummm > is the parent child selector...you were using thead > th that will always return null asl long as there is no direct child which is TH.

Answer (score 0):

More easy way to handle this question

```html
<table id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Mon</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Tue</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Wed</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Thr</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Fri</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Sat</th>
            <th style='width: 80px'>Sun</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        test($('#table1'));
    });
    function test(table) {
        $.each($(table).find("th"), function (key, val2) {
            alert(val2.innerHTML);
            alert($(val2).html());
        });
    }
</script>
```